# Compare Lists of Pairs to find similars

Tags: java, algorithm

```
Movie1{{'hello',5},{'foo',3}}
Movie2{{'hi',2},{'foo',2}}
```

While testing i am testing with 2 movies each has around 20 unique words grouped in pairs of word and frequency

```
public ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> getWordsAndFrequency() {

        String[] keys = description.split(" ");
        String[] uniqueKeys;
        int count = 0;
        uniqueKeys = getUniqueKeys(keys);

        for (String key : uniqueKeys) {
            if (null == key) {
                break;
            }

            for (String s : keys) {
                if (key.equals(s)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            words.add(Pair.of(key, count));
            count = 0;
        }
        sortWords(words);

        return words;
    }
```

Comment: Whats `Pair`? Is it from a third party library?

Comment: @ChetanKinger yes from appache commons http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html

Comment: Can you post the getWordsAndFrequency method? And how you are constructing it?

Comment: @code578841441 How do you know the loop runs infinitely? Did you try a test with a small data set to confirm this?

Comment: @nitegazer2003 i have added it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is your getWordsAndFrequency() method actually adds more entries to `words`. So each time you call it the word list gets longer and longer. To fix this, you should calculate the words and frequency once and add these Pairs to the list, then just return the list in the getWordsAndFrequency() method rather than calculating it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the data (that is currently stored in an arraylist of pairs) in a hashmap?
You can then compute the intersection of the sets of keywords between two movies and add their scores

For example:

```
Map<String, Integer> keyWordsMovie1 = movie1.getWordsAndFrequency();
Map<String, Integer> keyWordsMovie2 = movie2.getWordsAndFrequency();
Set<String> commonKeyWords = new HashSet<String>(keyWordsMovie1.keySet()); //set of all keywords in movie1
intersection.retainAll(keyWordsMovie2.keySet());

for (String keyWord : intersection){
    int freq1 = keyWordsMovie1.get(keyWord);
    int freq2 = keyWordsMovie2.get(keyWord);    
    //you now have the frequencies of the keyword in both movies
}
```

Comment: what is intersection?

Comment: the intersection of two sets will give you the common elements of the sets. So in your case, it will give you the list of all the keywords that are common between the two movies